# can't connect to webserver over http outside LAN

Tags: apache-http-server, port-forwarding, webserver, httpd, debian-lenny

I ran into a problem when working on my webserver.

Before I chaged anything connecting to `http://my.domain/` sent me to the proper `index.php` page.

When I started to work on this server, running Debian 5.0 Lenny (Yes, a very old version of Debian), I updated the packages to the latest version of Debian Lenny.

Then I changed `index.php` to `Xindex.php` and made a new html file called `index.html`. connecting to `http://192.168.1.xxx/` sends me to this `index.html` file. Everything's fine. Now I tried `http://my.domain/`. but then I get the error: `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

The weird thing is that my FTP server does work. before and after: `ftp://my.domain/` (same device)

Since it has worked, I assume that my ISP isn’t a problem. Because the HTTP connection works inside the LAN, I also assume that the server software is working properly.

my port forwarding 'shoud' work, (at least, FTP port 21 does):

```
21 > 21  192.168.1.xxx
80 > 80  192.168.1.xxx
```

Where could things be going wrong?

I have a WD (my book live) running Debian 5.0 Lenny, (actual OS: WDcloud 2.6). It uses Apache2 and httpd (it's an embedded device but I can SSH into it.)

EDIT: I found httpd.conf to be empty.

Comment: (1)Wow a lot going on here, is this a server or some embedded device (storage device with enhanced features [aka 'cloud'])? (2)My first thought is DNS, does the my.domain work inside the LAN? (3)Who is your internet DNS host, if you have home internet its likely DHCP meaning your internet IP changes & you have to update your DNS somehow (router can do) so they can relate my.domain to your changing DHCP internet IP

Comment: Have you tried `ping my.domain` from the command line? What about traceroute?

Comment: ping works. 0% loss, @OlafDietsche. how is the FTP working with the same domain "if" the IP address is wrong, @gregg?

Comment: your isp might block port 80, sometimes at random. test another port?

Comment: Okay, My ISP says: "We are currently working on our services" and I cannot access my router anymore, this might be the problem I'm not sure since this wasn't the case just an hour ago. It's late in the evening, I'll check it again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your web server is an Apache web server. Try to restart Apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Then read the lastest messages in /var/log/syslog:

```
tail /var/log/syslog
```

Those messages could help you.

Have you checked your virtual site in /etc/apache2/?

Your DirectoryIndex for your my.domain virtual site could point to index.php instead index.html.

Comment: Well, Thank you, I found out that Apache2 is indeed the websever. I also found httpd to be installed. However, `service` is not installed. I'll try to find what package I need for this. Also, what do you mean by virtual site in etc/apache2/. I only see some configuration files there. syslog also doesn't exist but there are a few other .log files with useful information.

Comment: I used `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` `" stop` instead.

Comment: Still the same problem. FTP works, SSH works, but no HTTP through `my.domain`. `192.168.1.xxx` does work for everything.

Comment: Could this all be because httpd.conf is empty?